# Jump to App from custom bootloader in TMS320 digital media processor

Tags: boot, bootloader, flash-memory, tms

I am working on a boot loader for TMS320DM6437. The idea is to create 2 independent firmware that one will update another. In firmware1 I will download firmware2 file and write it to NOR flash in a specified address. Both firmware are stored in NOR flash in ais format. Now I have two applications in flash. One is my custom boot loader and the second one is my main project. I want to know how I can jump from the first program to the second program located at a specified address. I also expect information about documents which may help me to create custom bootloader

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

You can jump to the [entry point](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Accessing_c_int00). I'm using this approach on TMS320 2802x and 2803x, but it should be the same.
The symbol of the entry point is c_int00.
To get to know the address of c_int00 in the second application, you have to fix the Run-Time Support (RTS) library at a specific address, by modifying the linker command file.

Otherwise you can leave the RTS unconstrained, and create a C variable (at a fixed address) that is initialized with the value of cint_00. Using this method your memory map is more flexible and you can add, togheter with the C variable, a comprehensive data structure with other information for your bootloader, e.g. CRC, version number, etc.

Be carefull with the (re)initialization of the peripherals in the second application, since you are not starting from a hardware reset, and you may need to explicity reset some more registers, or clear interrupt requests.